# OpenID Session Fixation with CSRF

Tags: session-management, csrf, openid, session-fixation

[This answer describes](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/when-the-use-of-a-antiforgerytoken-is-not-required-needed/2126#2126) a situation where CSRF can be used to trick an end user to enter a credit card into another person's Paypal account.  It also highlights the fact that state-changing GET requests are just as bad a POST requests.

This is pretty simple to understand when dealing with a single forms based authentication.  But if we introduce an authentication system based on GETs and POSTs to different domains that we don't "own", I'm not sure how to prevent CSRF in that situation.

> If I were to extend this to OpenID, does this mean that a user could inject their OpenID credentials into my session?

What is the right way to address this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer my own question since I haven't seen this practice be encouraged in [various SDKs](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8396) and [code samples](http://acs.codeplex.com/).  Here is my theory:

Upon clicking the "sign in" button on the Relying Party (RP), two things should happen:

1. Write a random value to a `SECURE` `HTTPOnly` domain cookie
2. Then have the IDP redirect back to https://www.host.com/account/signin?csrf=myrandom 
    where "myrandom" equals the value within the cookie.
3. When the OpenID process signs you in, then it will POST to the above URL, you can then grab the CSRF string, and compare that to the cookie.

Let me know if you see any flaws in this approach

Comment: "_a **SECURE** HTTPOnly domain cookie_" What is the point of the "secure" part?

Comment: @curiousguy it is an optional feature for this specific scenario, but in general, all pages after initial authentication should be HTTPS only.  If I'm following that best practice I don't see any reason to explicitly omit it.

Comment: Then why is the www.host.com site not in HTTPS also?

Comment: @curiousguy Wow! I just fixed that horrible typo.  Thanks for the catch

Comment: @makerofthings Your approach is correct, see e.g. this white paper http://seclab.stanford.edu/websec/csrf/csrf.pdf where authors propose just this for OpenID CSRF protection.

Comment: For extra security, in step 2, send HMAC-SHA1 of your random value to the 3rd party server instead of sending the raw secret.